# Передача двумерного массива в конструктор

Tags: c++, массивы, конструктор, вектор

Здравствуйте! У меня есть код

```
const Level levels[] = 
{
  Level(
        {
          {Block, Block, Block,     Block,        Block, Block},
          {Block, Empty, Empty,     Empty ,       Empty, Block},
          {Block, Empty, Block,     Player|Empty, Empty, Block},
          {Block, Empty, Box|Empty, Box|Aim,      Empty, Block},
          {Block, Empty, Aim,       Box|Aim,      Empty, Block},
          {Block, Empty, Empty,     Empty,        Empty, Block},
          {Block, Block, Block,     Block,        Block, Block},
        }, 6, 7)
};
```

Конструктор `Level` выглядит так:

```
Level::Level(int **room, int w, int h)
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
level.h:23:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-      enclosed initializer list>' to 'int**'
```

Скажите, есть ли способ передать массив в конструктор, или нужно использовать, например, `vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int ** m` - это не указатель на двумерный массив. Это указатель на указатель на массив m. Чтобы передать двумерный массив, обычно передают указатель на m `int *m` и обращаются к элементам  так: `m + (номер_строки * длина_строки) + номер_столбца`.